# how to create DataFrame if I can not use the SparkContext?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
def predict(model: LRModel,query: Query): PredictedResult = {

val categorical_val = Array[String]("Type","Month","Dept","Size","IsHoliday")
val ordinary_val = Array[String]() 

val sc = new SparkContext()
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val query_seq = sc.parallelize(Seq(query))
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(query_seq).toDF("Type","Month","Dept","Size","IsHoliday")

val features = process_Data(df = df,categorical_val = categorical_val,ordinary_val = ordinary_val)
val label = model.linear.predict(Vectors.dense(features))
new PredictedResult(label) }
```

Im trying to convert Seq to DataFrame, but I find there are many methods using SparkContext to create online. The problem is that I do not have the para SparkContext,So I want to ask if there are some other ways to create DataFrame. Im new to Scala and Spark!

Comment: You cannot create a Dataframe without the sparkContext.

Comment: you don't need to create the SparkContext inside this method, you can just pass it as an parameter

Comment: @RaphaelRoth  'predict' is a function of PredictionIO, it was defined like this and I can't modify the para of this function. But I have figured it out by using the method of answer which I accepted.

Comment: @Constantine Yeah! You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SparkContext the main entry point for Spark functionality. A SparkContext represents the connection to a Spark cluster, and can be used to create RDDs, accumulators and broadcast variables on that cluster. DataFrame is a distributed collection of data organized into named columns. You can checkout the documentation here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/sql-programming-guide.html.

You can create a DataFrame from Seq as given below:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val df = Seq(("A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1"), ("A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2")).toDF("Type","Month","Dept","Size","IsHoliday")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer first.But this is not what I need now. I need a method to create Dataframe or convert Seq to DataFrame without the use of SparkContext

Comment: You can create the dataframe from Seq as shown above

Comment: what is the 'spark' of 'import spark.implicits._' ? how can I get it?

Comment: @xiuchaowu  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ClusterUberStream")
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[2]").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._

Comment: @xiuchao wu (Scala-specific) Implicit methods available in Scala for converting common Scala objects into DataFrames.